# Make a constructor that takes arguments without 'new'

Tags: java, class

I want to make a class that works like String, i.e doesn't require `new String("value");`.

 **For example:**

```
public class Number { ... }

// main
Number num = 5;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Not with Java, consider taking a look at Scala though.  That language can do it, and it runs on the JVM too.  The closest that Java can do is auto boxing and string literals which are hard wired in the compiler.

Comment: @ChrisK Isn't the String class written in Java though?

Comment: yes, the String class does exist in Java however it is treated as a special citizen by the Java compiler;  which treats string literals in a very special way that cannot be duplicated as cleanly from the Java language level.  The Java compiler does not support extensions for adding your own custom syntax.  It only supports constructors, methods, static methods, inheritance and so forth.

Comment: Not with Java, in C# you can have declared `implicit operator` for that purpose. Takea look at Scala

Comment: If Integer class wasn't a "final" class maybe you could extend it. This is possible in java last editions (i guess after java 5):

Integer integer = 5;//then this will be an Integer object

This property named "auto-boxing"

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no.

The long answer, you wouldn't want that behavior.

The cool thing about a strict OO language is you can ensure that an object is an object... the problem with java is that its a class based language, and less of an OO language... which causes oddities like this.

```
int myInt = 5; //primitive assignment.
```

This is a value, it is not an object and does not conform to the standards of what an object represents in Java.

```
Integer myInt = new Integer(5);
```

is creating a new object in memory, assigning a reference to it, and then any "passing" of this object happens by reference.

There are many frameworks that can give you a semblance of this assignment, but the `new` lets you know that you are creating a brand new object and not simply the value of some random section of memory that happens to be declared as a string of integer bits.

Answer (score 1):

Like AnthonyJClink said, you can't. But.. you can (kinda) shorten your instantiation code by not using the `new` keyword if you instantiate your instance in static method of your class. For example:

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyClass(){
    }

    public static MyClass create(){
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass instance = MyClass.create(); // Add parameters as needed
    }
}
```

It reminds me of methods like `int b = Integer.parseInt("444");` It makes your code more readable in some cases. It really depends on your needs. This public static instantiation is also often used with singletons `getInstance()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you are looking to syntactic alternatives, there are some alternatives to constructors, that have their application.

Enums - not what you are looking for.

Static factory methods.

```
Rule x = Rules.def("abc");
Rule y = def("abc"); // Static import

public abstract class Rules { // Factory
    public static Rule def(String s):
```

(One can drop the class name not only by a static import, but also by being inside a super class.)

```
class Grammar { protected Rule def(String s) { ... } }

Grammar g = new Grammar() {{
     Rule x = def("abc");
}};
```

Builders, fluent API

```
Grammar g = GrammarBuilder.grammar("Pascal")
   .rule("S")
        .seq()
            .keyword("PROGRAM");
            .nont("Decl")
            .nont("Block")
            .endseq()
        .endrule()
   .rule("Decl")
        ...
```

Builders, fluent API

```
Grammar g = grammar("Pascal",
   rule("S",
        seq(
            .keyword("PROGRAM");
            .nont("Decl")
            .nont("Block")
            .endseq()
        )),
   rule("Decl",
        ...)
);
```

Java 8 lambdas assigning to functional interfaces

```
Producer<String> x = () -> "beep";
x = () -> x.apply() + x.apply();
System.out.println(x.apply());
```